# How does Kotlin choose the generic overloaded function to call?

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I'm trying to write serialization functions to be able to serialize any vector (=ArrayList) in Kotlin, as well as primitive types and classes extending a `Serialize` class having a `toBinary()` function.
I also have a custom `WriteDataStream` class (code below) to serialize fields with the right format, endianness, etc.

I'm new to Kotlin but have experience in C++. In C++, I used templates and template specialization to solve that problem easily, but with Kotlin I've been struggling for a few days, without success.

I have a custom vector class `MyVector` which extends `ArrayList` and adds a maximum size. I want to serialize it with any generic type `T`, including inner vectors like a `MyVector<MyVector<MyClass>>`.

My `WriteDataStream` contains the following:

```
inline fun <reified T> write(vector: MyVector<T>) {
    this.writeSize(vector.size.toULong(), vector.MAX_SIZE)
    for (element in vector) {
        write<T>(element)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T: Serialize> write(value: T) {
    writeSerialize(value as Serialize)
}

inline fun <reified T> write(value: T) {
    when (T::class) {
        UByte::class -> {
            writeUInt8(value as UByte)
        }
        UShort::class -> {
            writeUInt16(value as UShort)
        }
        UInt::class -> {
            writeUInt32(value as UInt)
        }
        ULong::class -> {
            writeUInt64(value as ULong)
        }
        Byte::class -> {
            writeInt8(value as Byte)
        }
        Short::class -> {
            writeInt16(value as Short)
        }
        Int::class -> {
            writeInt32(value as Int)
        }
        Long::class -> {
            writeInt64(value as Long)
        }
        Boolean::class -> {
            writeBoolean(value as Boolean)
        }
        Float::class -> {
            writeFloat(value as Float)
        }
        Double::class -> {
            writeDouble(value as Double)
        }
        else -> {
            error("Default serialization:" + T::class.qualifiedName)
        }
    }
}
```

All the underlying functions writeXXX() are tested and work fine. However, when tying to serialize a MyVector with a class extending Serialize, I fall in the "Default serialization" case:

```
@Test
fun writeVectorOfStructure() {
    class TestStructure: Serialize() {
        override fun toBinary(stream: WriteDataStream) {
            stream.writeUInt32(17U)
            stream.writeUInt8(3U)
            stream.writeDouble(555.555)
        }
    }
    val value = MyVector<TestStructure>(MAX_SIZE, arrayListOf(TestStructure(), TestStructure()))
    writeStream.write(value)
    val bytes: UByteArray = writeStream.byteArray()
    Assert.assertEquals(bytes.size, 28) // = 2 (for size) + 2*(4+1+8) = 28 bytes
}
```

**So my question is**: Why does Kotlin not use the function

```
inline fun <reified T: Serialize> write(value: T)
```

when it serializes an element of the vector (`write<T>(element)`) with generic `T = Serialize`, but instead uses the more generic one?

```
inline fun <reified T> write(value: T)
```

In C++, the compiler always uses the most fitted function.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation in Kotlin?
I have tried with and without reified types, I have tried a non-generic function as well: `inline fun write(value: Serialize)`, but without success. The only thing that seems to work was to add a case for classes "instance of" Serialize in the fully-generic `inline fun <reified T> write(value: T)`, but this is not really a nice solution.

Thanks you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[JVM and its bad implementation of generics](https://www.artima.com/intv/generics.html)**

You are a victim of Java's implementation of generics, more specifically the [erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure). `C++` uses what is called type expansion to implement generics, meaning if you declare `MyType<A>` and `MyType<B>`, at `runtime` you will have two different types, language `runtime` will create them for you.

On the other hand what Java does is called the erasure implementation. so in java world when you say `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`, at runtime they are both identical types, that is system doesn't have any information to make a distinction between both of these, they are `List` type (***Note that there is no type parameter, it got removed during the compilation***).

**Lets decompile your code and see for yourself**

I wrote following code in kotlin, it matches yours

```
class SomeType {
    inline fun <reified T: String> write(value: T) {}
    inline fun <reified T> write(value: T) {}

    inline fun <reified T: Any> write(vector: List<T>) {
        for (element in vector) {
            write(element)
        }
    }
}
```

And when I decompile the code it gives me following. (Only relevant code included)

```
public final class SomeType {
   public final void write(@NotNull String value) {}
   public final void write(Object value) {}

   public final void write(@NotNull List vector) {
      boolean var6;
      for(Iterator var4 = vector.iterator(); var4.hasNext(); var6 = false) {
         Object element = var4.next();
      }
   }
}
```

Look at the `write(vector: List<T>)` method's decompilation. parameter type got changed to `List` which is a [Raw Type](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#What%20is%20the%20raw%20type?) and its components are objects.

And for an `Object` best method match is `public final void write(Object value)` and not the one with `String` or in your case `Serialize`.